# Why is .NET selecting base class from incorrect version of the assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, clr

I have a unit test that depends on a type `Derived` that inherits from a base class `Base`. `Derived` and `Base` are in separate third-party assemblies `Derived.dll` and `Base.dll`(2). Both DLLs are strong-named. An older version of `Base.dll`(1) is also loaded by the Visual Studio test executor. When I construct an instance of `Derived`, it's base type is the `Base` found in the `Base.dll`(1) rather than `Base.dll`(2). When I then make a call to a virtual method defined in `Base.dll`(2), a `MissingMethodException` is thrown.

Why is .NET selecting from the older DLL rather than the one that matches the version of the reference?

Comment: Is there a chance that these types have been registered to the Global Assembly Cache? There are documents on how the .NET runtime locates assemblies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies), and there are a few places where strongly typed assemblies can be placed that will prioritize their being selected for loading. Any chance you're dealing with different versions of Crystal Reports?

Comment: @JonathonChase Both versions of the assembly are being loaded, so I don't think this GAC issue. (I could be wrong here though.) This is actually Newtonsoft.Json and NS.Json.Bson.

Comment: If @JonathonChase is correct then you should see that while debugging. Take a look at the modules windows from where those dlls are loaded. Some testrunners do shadow copying of the assemblies that are used in tests that could also be a problem if copying fails somehow but the modules windows should give you hints.

Comment: From the output log and the debugger, I can confirm that both the Base dlls are being loaded before the derived DLL and that `Derived` is inheriting from the older, incorrect DLL

Comment: Is there any reason you can't add an assembly binding redirect to the latter version in your test project? I would expect that Visual Studio would be suggesting that you do so due to multiple versions being referenced.

Comment: The older DLL is being loaded by path rather than with an assembly name, which I think is preventing any binding redirects from taking effect. This is what FUSLOGVW is showing for the load: 
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: I was able to fix this by getting MSBuild to generate binding redirects for VsTest: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/391